# Count the number of a

Tags: kotlin

I have this code :

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
var a = "banana, eat, one"
var a1 = a1.split("a").toMutableList()
a1.sortBy { it.toCharArray().count { it == 'a' } }
}
```

This code allows me to sort my list a1 by number of a but I would like to have for each words (banana, eat, one) the number of a. I thought to create a HashMap something like this :
(banana,3)
(eat,1)
(one,0)

But I don't know if there is a function which allows me to do this ?

Could you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code didn't compile, but I assume you meant to use `a` in the second line and split on `,`. If so, you can use [`associateWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-with.html) to create a `Map` where the keys are your words, and the values are the counts of `'a'` in each:

```
val a = "banana, eat, one"
val a1 = a.split(", ").toMutableList()
val a2 = a1.associateWith { word -> word.count { char -> char == 'a' } } 

println(a2) // {banana=3, eat=1, one=0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    val input = "banana, eat, one"
    // split the words
    val split = input.split(",")

    val map = HashMap<String, Int>()
    for (word in split) {
        var countA = 0

        // count the character 'a' per word
        for (character in word) {
            if (character == 'a' || character == 'A') {
                countA++
            }
        }
        map[word] = countA
    }
    println(map)
}
```

Comment: Because Kotlin is designed to reduce boilerplate. It has many methods to simplify such algorithms. Now I see java.

Comment: Your solution is very manual and Java-like, but it does in fact work. Shouldn't really be downvoted, it's just not the best possible answer.

Comment: It's true what you said. Thanks for the feedback. Your solutions are shorter and faster to read. But when you are not able to write such code and need to ask this question, it is more likely that my code is easier to understand what it does.

Answer (score -2):

```
"banana, eat, one".split(",").associateBy({ it }, { it.count { it.toLowerCase() == 'a' } })
```